# I used owl carousel. I want to this carousel stop on main screen. but its continue scroll in mobile version.

Tags: css, carousel

I used owl carousel. I want to this carousel stop on main screen. but it will be continue scroll in mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [api](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) it has an `autoPlay` option. So, before initialising the carousel, check what device you are on and pass in the appropriate setting.